# The VMware Authorization Service is not running

Tags: service, vmware

windows could not start vmware authorise service on local computer.

> Error 1075 : the dependency service does not exist or has been marked
>   as deletion

I have installed **windows7 home basic**  so i am not geeting any 
 **- local user and group** option in *computer managment* and i am already login as Admin though i am not able to start service **manually**

Comment: Click your VMware installer again to repair it (do not restart your machine). The VMware services will be started. I'm using VMware 9 and runing on windows 8, I could not find the solution to workaround this issue, I think it's bug.

Comment: iDev has the correct answer.  Should not need repaired, most likely just the service not running.

Comment: Please check iDev's correct answer as verified !!

Comment: @TomStickel Error 1075 occurs when trying to start the service.  Apparently, the installer won't repair unless the versions match exactly, either.  I'm running 9.0.4 and the installer is for 9.0.2 so it won't repair.  Very annoying.

Answer (score 101):

To fix this solution i followed:
[this](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1007131)

1.Click Start and then type Run

2.Type services.msc and click OK

3.Scroll down the list and locate that the VMware Authorization service.

4.Click Start the service, unless the service is showing a status of Started.

Comment: Exactly!  This is the correct answer to blindly re-install /reboot that is just crazy.

Comment: this is the most sensible answer and should be the first thing to be checked .

Comment: The Error 1075 is what you get when you try to start the VMware Authorization Service.

Comment: This answer is getting a lot of upvotes - note that this quoted VMWare KB article is addressing a different problem then the OP had (service _can't_ start, not service isn't running).  I myself had this problem, and this solution didn't fix it.  Are the people who are upvoting this answer really getting an error when starting up the VMWare Authorization Service?  Or are they seeing errors as a result of that service being down.

Comment: @TomStickel a lots of people including me, how have this question already tried this, and failed to start the service, the service is automatic, and it must start automatically when it didnt start, we cant just start the service manually(if you try that you will get error) so I think it is not a solution at all!

Comment: On windows 10, Re-running the installer and selecting "repair" fixed this problem for me.

Comment: This works, but I had to redo this after every startup. An update of the vmware player solved it magically, lol.

Answer (score 37):

This problem was solved for me by repairing `vmware` with the run installer which fixed the services correctly.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful.

Comment: Thank you for that comment, @Simon.

Answer (score 6):

I followed Telvin's suggestion and it worked on Windows 7:

1. Run the VMware installer by right clicking on it and selecting "Run as Administrator"
2. In the resulting popup menu, select "Repair installation"

Answer (score 3):

1.Click Start and then type Run (or Windows button + R)

2.Type **services.msc** and click OK

3.Find all VMware services.

4.For each, click Start the service, unless the service is showing a status of Started.

- If "***Start* the service**" is **disappear**, please do these things before:

  1. Click Start and then type Run (or Windows button + R)
  2. Type **msconfig** and click OK
  3. In *Services* tab, find then check all VMware services checkboxes.
  4. Click **Apply** then **OK**.

Answer (score 2):

I've also had this problem recently.

The solution that worked for me was to uninstall vmware, restart windows, and the reinstall vmware.

Answer (score 2):

Run as admin - vmware workstation will do.

Answer (score 0):

Error in Events:

The application (VMware Workstation, from vendor VMware, Inc.) has the following problem: To function properly, VMware Workstation must be reinstalled after you upgrade Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by starting the service manually.

1. Type `services` in the Windows search bar.
2. Open Services; scroll to the VMware Authorization Service (should be close to the bottom of the page)
3. Double-click to open the Properties page of the service.
4. Change the startup type to Automatic and then start the service. That way, the service will be started automatically every time you log in.

More detailed info can be found at
[Powering on a virtual machine fails with the error: The VMware Authorization Service is not running (1007131)](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1007131)

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem: I have to start manually this service once in a while. For those of you who have the same problem you can create a bat file and execute it when the service is not running (VMAuthdService service). This doesn't solve the problem, it's just a kind of workaround. The content of the file is the following:

```
:: BatchGotAdmin
:-------------------------------------
REM  --> Check for permissions
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"

REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
    echo Requesting administrative privileges...
    goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )

:UACPrompt
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "%~s0", "", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    exit /B

:gotAdmin
    if exist "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" ( del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" )
    pushd "%CD%"
    CD /D "%~dp0"
:--------------------------------------

net start VMAuthdService
```

Name the file **Start Auth VmWare.bat**

Answer (score 0):

type `Services` at search, then start `Services`

[image]

then start all VM services

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try executing vmware as administrator

Answer (score -1):

This problem was solved for me by running VMware workstation as Windows administrator.
From the start menu right click on the VMware workstation, then select "Run as Administrator"